# Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer when hosting multiple Symfony projects

Tags: php, apache, symfony, debian

I actually host 2 Symfony 2.8 projects on my Debian local server. I configured Apache to serve my 2 applications with these 2 URL :

```
App1 : http://192.168.0.1
App2 : http://192.168.0.1/app2
```

When I am logged into my account in App1 and navigate to App2, Symfony throws this **warning :**

> Warning : Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer.

Here is my Apache virtual block **conf :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.0.1
    ServerAlias devserver

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.)
    RewriteRule . - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    DocumentRoot /var/www/app1/web
    Alias /app2 "/var/www/app2/web"

    <Directory /var/www/app1/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/app2/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app2/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/app_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/app_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I noticed I have no problem to navigate between my two applications when i am not logged in.

I have disabled all PHP accelerator and cleared the cache on both app, but still have this behavior.

Have you ever faced this problem ? Do you have any clue ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encountered the same problem, I figured out that the session was involved. I fixed the warning by adding a session name in `config.yml` :

```
framework:
    ...
    session:
        name: "app1"
```